# Attempting to set up Dual boot Win8.1/Ubuntu 16.04 and struggling

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

Using an Asus X551CA laptop running Windows 8.1.

I created a USB flash installer for Ubuntu 16.04 and attempted to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. During the install an alert came up suggesting that UEFI may not be the best option and inviting me to go back. Assuming that Windows may have been installed using BIOS (Legacy CSM in Asus-speak) I followed the guidance and the install completed fine. However there was no option to boot into Windows when I restarted.

I ran the installer again and opted for the UEFI route on the assumption that Windows was using UEFI, and that if I installed Ubuntu on the same basis this would resolve my problem. Same result - I was able to boot into Ubuntu but no sign of any option to boot into Windows.

Went back to the first install option and when complete ran boot-repair. Output is at http://paste2.org/fnFnN2mP

Now deeply confused and seeking guidance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Ubuntu did you run "sudo-update grub"? Also, did you check GParted to be sure that you didn't wipe your Windows partitions?

Comment: Certainly checked in GParted that the Windows partitions are all there, but didn't run sudo update-grub. Just did that, and on rebooting, I now have two Windows boot options (sda1 and sda2). Two options is certainly way better than none. Thank you!

Comment: Let me put that in an answer for others who may have this issue.

Comment: Both Ubuntu & Windows are installed in BIOS boot mode. But you ran Boot-Repair in UEFI boot mode. Best to always boot in BIOS mode to avoid issues. A normal grub update from Boot-Repair should also have run the `sudo update-grub`, but in UEFI mode it may not have. Also what version of Windows? If Windows 8 or later, grub will not find it until you turn off fast start up. And that would require you to directly boot Windows. And then from your Windows you need your Windows repair disk to allow you to fix Windows.

Comment: How do I control in which mode (BIOS or UEFI) to run Boot-Repair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `sudo-update grub` from terminal.

Grub will automatically detect Windows boot partitions; however, Fast startup must be disabled, and Windows must not be in a hibernated state.